# Create Service or Class in symfony

Tags: mongodb, symfony, dependency-injection

I created new Class to connect mongoDB, it's a singleton Class.

Do I have convert this Class in Service ?

When Use Service instead of Class ?

Is Service already Singleton?

My Service is

```
class MongoDB
{

    private $dbname;
    private $url;
    private $db;

    /**
     * MongoDB constructor.
     * @param $dbname
     * @param $url
     */
    public function __construct($dbname,$url)
    {
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function getMongoCon()
    {
        if ($this->db === null)
        {
            try {
                $connection = new \MongoClient($this->url);
                $this->db = $connection->selectDB($this->dbname);
            } catch (\MongoConnectionException $e) {
                die('Failed to connect to MongoDB '.$e->getMessage());
            }
            $this->db = $connection;
        }

        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

Comment: @radu-murzea has some good answers, but a bigger point is that Symfony and Doctrine already provide this for you and you shouldn't be writing this connection code yourself.  Please take a look at [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html)

Comment: @JasonRoman it doesn't work with symfony 3 in this moment

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work with Symfony 3? Is there something official that states it doesn't work?

Comment: When I try to install the bundle I get error like this
`Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0`, the error is very long but the conclusion is `don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take them point by point:

> Do I have convert this Class in Service ?

No, you don't **have** to. In typical use-cases it's recommended though, because you'll probably need to inject it into other services, which means it needs to be a service in order to be injectable.

> When Use Service instead of Class ?

The 2 are in 99% of cases not mutually exclusive. A service is defined by its class, arguments that can/must be passed to its constructor (a.k.a. its dependencies), tags etc. Or it can be a factory service or an abstract service or any other type provided by Symfony.

> Is Service already Singleton?

Yes and no. A service does not automatically become a singleton. Unless explicitly specified via scopes (which are deprecated since 2.8 and removed in 3.0), a service is only instantiated once within Symfony's container. Any subsequent attempts to retrieve it will return the same instance over and over.

---

I recommend you read a little more about dependency injection and how it's achieved in Symfony. It's basically the heart and core of the entire framework. Once you understand that part, everything else about the framework will be much much easier to grasp ;) .

PS: You did not implement the Singleton pattern correctly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Radu. My snippet is a service isn't Class. My class is http://pastebin.com/F0pGRPsR, And it's a singleton Class. With my service snippet in my first post, I can inject global param  ( from parameters.yml) to connect to my database. When I retrieve my service form Symfony's container I do `$conn = $this->get('mymongo')`. Isn't it the right implementation? Or I have to inject Class in my service?